# Is it possible to override the default button alignment using css?

Tags: button, alignment

I have generated multiple default 'buy now' buttons which I aligned to the right of their descriptive text by styling the `<form>` element in my css. Now the alignment has stopped working; the buttons now seem to be displayed in an invisible table that I can't override. I don't know what changed, and no css I've applied to the `<form>` element has any effect.

It's a Wordpress site, recently updated to 3.7.1. Example page:

http://www.loudoungiftsforgood.org/2013/10/10/all-ages-read-together/

Until recently the buttons were aligned to the bottom of each text paragraph with the following css (and the form code above the text in the html):

`form {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    margin-left:2.4em; }`

Is there another way of overriding the current alignment?

Comment: How would you like it displayed? Do you still want the paragraphs to wrap the main image?

Comment: I would like the text to wrap, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you want?

Otherwhise if you give the form a margin-top of -50px the buttons are nicely aligned next to the corresponding text.

grts

Comment: @user3075870 You should mark them as accepted answer if they fixed your problem and vote them up